# Add end of line or new line character in fifo pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

I want to implement a utility where I can capture the TCP server response and print it on the terminal on some interval.

Please refer below the code

```
#!/bin/bash
#creating two fresh fifo pipe
rm -f inputPipe
mkfifo inputPipe
rm -f outputPipe
mkfifo outputPipe

#opening them
perl -e 'open(my $fh, ">", "inputPipe"); sleep 3600 while 1' &
pid1=$!
perl -e 'open(my $fh, ">", "outputPipe"); sleep 3600 while 1' &
pid2=$!

#whatever I will write into inputPipe should go to TCP server and response of 
#Tcp server should capture in outputPipe
cat inputPipe | nc -v 192.168.1.105 19204 > outputPipe &
pid3=$!

#TCP buffer written into inputPipe that will go to TCP server and then server will respond
echo -e "\x5A\x01\0\x01\0\0\0\x1C\x04\x4C\0\0\0\0\0\0" > inputPipe
#continuously looking for server response and then after reading the response, again querying 
#same information again after 2 seconds
while true; 
  do 
**#main problem I am getting here while reading server response because in server response there are no any
#end of line or new character hence below read statement hanging for infinite.**
    if read line; 
    then 
      echo $line;
      sleep 2;
      echo -e "\x5A\x01\0\x01\0\0\0\x1C\x05\x15\0\0\0\0\0\0" > inputPipe
    fi 
  done <outputPipe
trap "rm -f inputPipe outputPipe" EXIT 
trap "kill -9 $pid1 $pid2 $pid3" EXIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the input pipe only once, (and also open it together with the output pipe):

```
{
    echo -e "\x5A\x01\0\x01\0\0\0\x1C\x04\x4C\0\0\0\0\0\0" >&3

    while true;  do 
        if read line; then 
            echo "$line"
            sleep 2
            echo -e "\x5A\x01\0\x01\0\0\0\x1C\x05\x15\0\0\0\0\0\0" >&3
        fi 
    done 
} <outputPipe 3>inputPipe
```

Also consider using `-r` option to `read`.

Might as well remove `cat`:

```
nc -v 192.168.1.105 19204 > outputPipe <inputPipe &
```

If this doesn't work, consider implementing a [Coproc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Coprocesses).

Comment: Thanks a lot @konsolebox
I fixed it in another way, I know first byte of my TCP response is always 0x5A so read line upto that character, and after that remove TCP header prefix from the response as I know my response body always start from '{' character.
while true; 
  do
    if read -r -d$'\x5A' line; 
    then
      tmp=${line#*\{}
      tchar='{'
      fstr="${tchar}${tmp}"
      clear
      echo $fstr;
      sleep 2; 
      echo -e "\x5A\x01\0\x01\0\0\0\x1C\x04\x4C\0\0\0\0\0\0" >&3
    fi 
  done <outputPipe 3>inputPipe

your input really help me a lot. Thanks a lot.